# How does a convolutional neural network connect to the multi-layered perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, convolution

Which operation takes place to produce the output from say a 9x9 filter and pass that output as the input to MLP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the last convolutional layer, you have `N` feature maps, with `WxH` resolution. This can be seen as a feature vector `X` of size `NxWxH` if you concatenate all the values.

This is how you *connect* it to an MLP: i.e `X` acts as an input of a linear transformation with nb. rows = MLP output and nb. columns = `NxWxH`.

Example: a simple convnet with 2 convolutional layers (x) for [traffic sign recognition](http://computer-vision-tjpn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/reference_papers/2-sermanet-ijcnn-11-mscnn.pdf) gives:

- input: 3 channels, width=32, height=32
- layer 1: 108 feature maps, width=14, height=14
- layer 2: 200 feature maps, width=5, height=5
- 2-layer classifier with 100 hidden units, and 43 output classes

So to connect it to the final MLP you *reshape* the outputs of layer 2 into a vector of 200x5x5=5000 elements.

This vector becomes the input for a linear transform of size 100 (rows) x 5000 (columns).

(x) convolution kernel size = 5, spatial pooling size = 2.

Comment: Incredible answer. Thank you